# Angular lazy loading breaks skeleton loading animations

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, skeleton-ui

I've seen a few other solutions ([Show activity Indicator while loading a lazy loaded Module in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981136/show-activity-indicator-while-loading-a-lazy-loaded-module-in-angular-2), [Showing a loading indicator for lazy loaded route module](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3505-showing-a-loading-indicator-for-lazy-loaded-route-modules-in-angular-6-1-7.htm) ) and a few others that I quickly skimmed but none address my issue.

My app grew too large and needed lazy loading. I have a skeleton-ui for loading indicators (vs a big spinner). As soon as I converted things to lazy loading it broke all the keyframe animations in my skeleton-ui.

I dont know exactly why it does it. It could be something built into the CSS, Angular, or even my app locking the UI until it parses the JS. I have no idea.

**How can I have lazy loading while still giving the user immideate feedback via a skeleton ui?**

Answer (score 0):

Use a loading spinner... due to the fact that you didn't provide code examples, it's hard to help you with your problem.

The reason, I guess, is overfetching CSS.