# Delay in route resolution for lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

I'm running into an issue with route resolution in my lazy loaded feature modules.

routerLink is showing an ellepsis (...) in the displayed route for a small period of time.  If I click on the link immediately I get an error that "cannot match any routes".  But if I hover over the link until the path resolves, then the transition occurs fine.

Is there a way to delay the route transition until the lazy load is complete, and the Router can resolve the target?

Comment: Please provide your code or an working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: Would it be possible to flip it around - load the module with the route initially, and load its child modules as the lazy loaded modules?

Comment: I'm thinking this is very much in line with what I need to do: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981136/